# How to practically check if a Hermitian matrix is an observable?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, observables

I get that in QM an observable corresponds to a Hermitian operator. And I also get that not all Hermitian operators will correspond to an observable - with all that $C^*algebra$ stuff. Is there a practical way to check if a Hermitian matrix corresponds to an observable. I did ask ChatGPT which said a Hermitian operator needs to satisfy normalizing condition. It says:

"For a quantum operator $A$ representing an observable, the normalizing condition is given by:

$\langle \psi|A^{\dagger}A|\psi\rangle = 1$

where $|\psi\rangle$ is the state of the system and $A^{\dagger}$ is the conjugate transpose of $A$. The normalizing condition ensures that the expectation value of the observable is equal to $1$ when the system is in a normalized state."

I tried to find a reference for this but couldn't find any. And I am not able to trust ChatGPT without asking experts here.

Also, as an aside, I have a Hermitian matrix with a normalized state and eigenstates (that is $\langle \psi | \psi \rangle = 1$ and $\langle v_i|v_i \rangle = 1$, for all eigenstates $v_i$), and I tried to find the sum of the probability amplitudes,

$ \sum_{i=1}^n |\langle v_i | \psi \rangle |^2 \neq 1$

So, I am suspecting my operator is not an observable. But I don't know a practical way to test that (btw, the above ChatGPT "test" fails). If there is a factor that would make $|\langle v_i | \psi \rangle |^2$ as a proper probabilty amplitude, that would be great to know as well.

Thanks.

Comment: As a side note, just because an operator defines a measurement in quantum mechanics does not mean that it is physically realizable. The most trivial measurement operator is the unity operator. It measures the position of a quantum in the usual position basis that we express the Schroedinger equation in. Such a measurement does not exist because there is no matter that absorbs energy with 100% efficiency and that can fill all of space homogeneously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you've got from ChatGPT is amazingly wrong, operator representing an observable in quantum theory need not obey the equation
$$
\langle \psi | A^\dagger A |\psi\rangle = 1
$$

and even writing it this way reveals absence of understanding of the topic. Operators representing observables are self-adjoint (or something close), so $A^\dagger = A$, and the equation above could be written more simply as
$$
\langle \psi|  A^2 |\psi\rangle = 1.
$$
Thus the equation states average expected value of square of  the quantity is 1. This is not correct except in special cases when $\psi$ is chosen in such a way as to give that average value equal to 1.

Thus this condition is simply not satisfied in general.

> Is there a practical way to check if a Hermitian matrix corresponds to an observable.

No, because the matrix is not enough to define the operator, you need to know what basis it refers to. If you know that basis $\phi_n$, then you can check against known operators. On one hand, you have the Hermitian matrix $A_{mn}$; on the other hand, you can calculate another Hermitian matrix

$$
B_{mn} = \langle \phi_m|\hat{B}|\phi_n\rangle
$$
for various known operators $\hat{B}$ representing observables.

If your initial matrix $A_{mn}$ equals to $B'_{mn}$ for some known operator $\hat{B}'$, you can conclude the operator $\hat{A}$ is the same as the operator $\hat{B}$ and represents the same observable.

Comment: Yes, I thought ChatGPT could be wrong (other than concisely writing $A^2$, which I will excuse ChatGPT) when it said expectation is 1.